# It was done with the help of John, Sam, and "me"—or "myself"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which is correct: "It was done with the help of John, Sam and me" or "It was done with the help of John, Sam and myself"

Comment: or "John, Sam and I helped do it".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "me", the word is not interchangeable with "myself" so no use of "myself" in that context would be correct.

"I did it myself" or "I will take it to the shop myself" is correct. Otherwise it's "me".

Comment: I'll explain my downvote: 'myself' has a totally acceptable usage as a stressed form, and there are situations where it is the better choice. << "I know that nobody went to their aid." ... "That's not true ... people going to help included Tom, Jill, Ali, and myself." >>

Comment: I'm putting my head on the block in defence of the answer, which I feel is not deserving of a downvote. *Me* is surely the correct answer, even if *myself* is frequently heard in such a context. The question is at what point usage translates into acceptability. It's not unusual to hear: *Myself and a friend were .......* but surely it's not correct.

Comment: @RonaldSole I wouldn't put my head on the block for a matter of correctness. There are surely correct rules that apply to all English speakers. For instance *John loves Mary* will never be an acceptable form to mean that Mary loves John. But for instances like this, the best you can say is "correct with regard to." With regard to formal, standard English expression, the correct answer is *me*.

Answer (score -2):

I would go with *me*, since *myself* is used to refer a single person: myself.

Comment: Not sure what this was marked down for - looks correct to me.